# How to create an Admin user after creating a project in Apostrophe CMS

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Is there a way I can create an Admin user automatically via code in Apostrophe CMS after I created the project? Currently I still have to perform the node app.js apostrophe-users:add admin admin in CLI to have an Admin user.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a user with a password without pausing for a password prompt by piping the password into the command:

```
echo "wowsosecure" | node app apostrophe-users:add admin admin
```

This sets the password to:

`wowsosecure`

When passing passwords on the command line there is the risk that the command line could be observed via the `ps auxw` command or similar. This is not much of a risk on a dedicated server since the only non-root account available to be compromised would usually be the one for the website itself, which could set a password anyway. But it is worth mentioning. If it concerns you, you could pipe it in from a file rather than the "echo" command.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I include piping password in chaining commands. Just like the 1st proposal I received above?

Comment: Yes, you can include commands that involve pipes in a chain of commands.

Answer (score 0):

I think the CLI is the most *automatic* way of creating a user after project setup.

You could chain the commands together like

```
apos create-project your-project && cd your-project && npm install && node app apostrophe-users:add admin admin
```

and create a shortcut for that in your favorite terminal.

Comment: Thank you very much :), I will try this.